# Distribute Column Width on Table of Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My goal is to go to the top of the Word document, find the 6th table, and format the table to "Arial" and font 9 and distribute the column width.

The problem is that it doesn't distribute the column width but does the other two.

```
Sub TableFormat()

Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
    Selection.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Selection.Font.Size = 9
       If Selection.Cells.Count >= 2 Then
          Selection.Cells.DistributeWidth
       End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an aside, I think you can select the 6th table in the document like so `ActiveDocument.Tables(6).Columns.DistributeWidth`

Comment: But I get the feeling that, if your code works on the other tables, that the contents of the 6th one might be the actual problem instead of the code

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I think "does the other 2" refers to the other two things that should be done to the table, not to `DistributeWidth` working only in some cases...

Comment: If you can use `Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1` to go to the first table, why jump through all the `Which:=GoToNext` hoops to go to the 6th table, why not just `Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 6` in the first place?

Comment: And maybe it's just me not knowing the Word OM at all, but `Selection.Tables(1).Select` looks like it's working on the first table, not the one you've spent all that time jumping to. Why not get rid of all the lines above that and simply `Selection.Tables(6).Select` instead?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, not knowing the OM... Selection.Tables(1) works with the first table *in the selection*. And the code isn't supposed to go to a particular page, but to a table, calculated from the first page.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick for you without all that crazy `Select`ing :)

```
Sub TableFormat()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(6)
        With .Range.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 9
        End With

        If .Columns.count > 1 Then .Columns.DistributeWidth
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Cells.DistributeWidth` to `Columns.DistributeWidth`